# VB or C# for Executing an exe in a subfolder

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm creating a custom game launcher and I need to add arguments to it so I used Process.Start() but the problem is it is in a subfolder of the root folder.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileName:="/bin/something.exe", arguments:="service15")
```

but when I use that I end up with:

> The system cannot find the file specified

but the file really exists there I promise. I do really want to run it on that way without moving the app to where the something.exe found.

Comment: File paths in windows use the back slash and should be either absolute or relative to where the currently executing file is located. So the error is correct, the file cannot be found because you did not specify the path correctly. What the path should be I/we do not know because you did not provide any information regarding the folder structure of your app or the one you are calling.

Comment: How is your error relevant to your title and tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get current working directory and then add sub folder path.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/bin/something.exe", "service15")
```

this should work.

Comment: You may use &quot;&amp;&quot; operator instead of &quot;+&quot; operator. Since &quot;+&quot; is used to adding values and &quot;&amp;&quot; is used to concatenate strings. If `Option Strict`, was turned on, it would show an error.